# about c++ templates and parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, parameter-pack

```
template<class... Cs>
void func(Cs... cs){
};
template<class T, class... Cs>

void func1(T s){

    func<Cs...>(/* the problem */);
};

int main(){
    char s[]="HI THERE!";
    func1<char*,char,char,char>(s);
    return 0;
}
```

so the func1() call the func(), the two functions are specialized by the same template parameter pack, the function func1() take a known parameter "s" and we assume that it can produce and provide the parameters values from that `s` to the func()  , but how can we do that.

the problem is hard to me to explain i hope u get the point.

edit: lets say that the args that  the `func1()` passes to `func()` follow this pattern `s[0],s[1],...` , is depend on the parameter pack actually

Comment: What do you expect the arguments to the `func` call to be, in this specific case? `s[0]`, `s[1]` and `s[2]`? What if `T` is some other type?

Comment: It is not clear what output you expect from the program. Provide your expected output in the question.

Comment: @user17732522 it's depend on the parameter pack  , if it is ```<char,char>``` it's ```s[0]```,```s[1]``` , if it is ```<char,char,char>``` its would be ```s[0]```,```s[1]```,```s[2]``` and so on , that the problem actual who to passe those args to ```func()``` .

Comment: `func1` needs to be `void func1(T s, Cs... cs)` and then you can forward those arguments to `func`.

Comment: we assume we can get the args values from ```s``` so we dont need passe them to the ```func1()``` .

Comment: @HestiaGaia well, you can't simply **assume** it, please show how you'd like to actually get those out of `s`.(for example, you show you want an `int` in the chat in the answer, [link](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/54857277#54857277), which is not matching this post)

Comment: lets say that s is a ```struct{ int n; char c, bool f }``` and we get them from the struct like s.a or s->a ... .the point is that we can get them for sure.

Comment: @HestiaGaia sorry then it wouldn't work here. it's not how template work. (at least without customized traits/getters)

Comment: further explanation please

Comment: @HestiaGaia for example considering your existing 2 example. how the template knows you want `s.n` or `s[0]`? (how it even know it need to access `n` and not `m`)

Comment: if it's customized for each type... well then simply use overloads of functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you want to use the parameter pack and expand those number of elements in `s`:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>

template<class... Cs>
void func(Cs&&... cs){ // 'H', 'I', ' '
};

template<class T, std::size_t... I>
void func1_helper(T s, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    func(s[I]...);
}

template<class T, class... Cs>
void func1(T s){
    func1_helper(s, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Cs)>{});
};

int main(){
    char s[]="HI THERE!";
    func1<char*, char,char,char>(s);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see here, the actual types in the pack isn't needed. You could just as easily have supplied the number `3`:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>

template<class... Cs>
void func(Cs&&... cs){ // 'H', 'I', ' '
};

template<class T, std::size_t... I>
void func1_helper(T s, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    func(s[I]...);
}

template<std::size_t N, class T>
void func1(T s){
    func1_helper(s, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
};

int main(){
    char s[]="HI THERE!";
    func1<3>(s);
    return 0;
}
```

---

If you *really* want to pass a pack of types that are not exact matches to what you've got in your array:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template<class... Cs>
void func(Cs... cs){ // 'H', 'I', ' '
    // prints HI and the `int` value of ' ' (32 most likely):
    (..., (std::cout << cs));
};

template<class... Cs, class T, std::size_t... I>
void func1_helper(T s, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    func<Cs...>(s[I]...);
}

template<class T, class... Cs>
void func1(T s){
    func1_helper<Cs...>(s, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Cs)>{});
};

int main(){
    char s[]="HI THERE!";
    func1<char*, char,char,int>(s);
    return 0;
}
```

- `std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Cs)>{}` creates an object of type `std::index_sequence<0, 1, 2>` (in this case).
- In `func1_helper` the indices, `0, 1, 2` goes into the parameter pack `size_t... I` to match the anonymous `index_sequence<I...>` argument.
- `I` is then used to expand `s[I]...` into `s[0], s[1], s[2]`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo i kinda undestand the solotion here i guess ( im not quoit familiar with the usage of index_sequence but i ve got the point ), but i have a question: what if the T s [ char* ] will expand to not [char,char,....] but is something like [char,int,...],

Comment: @HestiaGaia No, it will expand to `char, char, char` or `char&,char&,char&` in my example since I used forwarding references. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/TT3EnTKT6)

Comment: @TedLyngmo but what if we want something like this : https://ibb.co/r4KS2ck

Comment: @HestiaGaia Please, no pictures. Use https://godbolt.org/  or some other online compiler please.

Comment: @TedLyngmo https://godbolt.org/z/99K6jY4vc here we go .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246134/discussion-between-hestiagaia-and-ted-lyngmo).